# The name 'age' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program that determines whether the user is a club member or not and then based on their age display their discount amount. I have the program written but it is giving me some errors that I just cannot find the solution to. I have tried searching this site and others to find what I am doing wrong but every troubleshoot I did failed. I am a learning programmer so I am sure it's something really simply that I am missing. Any input on the problem would be greatly appreciated. 
I know why I am getting the error about age not existing in the current context, I just do not understand what I am missing in my code so that 'age' is processed correctly.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PA05
{
    class DiscountApp
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DisplayTitle();
            InputMembershipStatus(age);
            DetermineDiscount(age);
            TerminateProgram();
        }

        public static void DisplayTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Programming Assignment 5 - Determine Discount\n\tProgrammer: ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            DrawLine();
        }

        public static void InputMembershipStatus(int age)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you a Club Member? <Y or N>: ");
            string aValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (aValue == "Y" || aValue == "y" || aValue == "Yes" || aValue == "yes")
            {
                age = InputAge();
            }
            else if (aValue == "N" || aValue == "n" || aValue == "No" || aValue == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, discounts apply to Club Members only.");
                TerminateProgram();
            }

        }

        public static int InputAge()
        {
            int age;
            Console.Write("Please enter the customer's age: ");
            age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return age;

        }

        public static double DetermineDiscount(int age)
        {
            double discountAmount;
            if (age <= 10 || age >= 60)
            {
                discountAmount = .15;
                Console.WriteLine("The discount is a  {0:P2}", discountAmount);
            }
            else 
            {                
                discountAmount = .1;
                Console.WriteLine("The discount is b {0:P2}", discountAmount);
            }
            return discountAmount;
        }

        public static void DrawLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________________");
        }

        public static void TerminateProgram()
        {
            DrawLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the program...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Main` method uses the the variable `age`, even though it isn't defined anywhere. You're supposed to pass in an actual value for the `age` parameter.

Comment: I understand that much, but even when I declare the variable in the main method it still gives me errors relating to the two methods 'InputMembershipStatus()' and 'DertermineDiscount()'
Really what I need to know is how I what I need to do to process the 'age' variable to be processed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that variables in c# have limited scope.  You cannot access a variable declared within another function like you're trying to do.

It looks like you're trying to *set* age in `InputMembershipStatus`.  What you want is a *return* variable:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DisplayTitle();
    // this age variable is declared inside Main 
    // and receives its value from InputMembershipStatus
    int age = InputMembershipStatus();
    DetermineDiscount(age);
    TerminateProgram();
}
```

and

```
// this function now returns an int instead of having a parameter
public static int InputMembershipStatus()
{
    int age = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Are you a Club Member? <Y or N>: ");
    string aValue = Console.ReadLine();
    if (aValue == "Y" || aValue == "y" || aValue == "Yes" || aValue == "yes")
    {
        age = InputAge();
    }
    else if (aValue == "N" || aValue == "n" || aValue == "No" || aValue == "no")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, discounts apply to Club Members only.");
        TerminateProgram();
    }

    return age;
}
```

I would read up on [variable scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) and [returning values from methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

Comment: This solved my problem and the program is running just fine now, Thank you! But I would like to be able to better understand just how it solved my problem, Would you mind elaborating on the solution?

Comment: @user2864614 
When you declare `int age` = 8 in the Main() of the program, `age` is only available in the scope of main. Your other functions can not access it. two possible solutions to this are the solution above, which is what i would recommend. this returns makes InputMembershipStatus return the value to main where it sets it to age. The other would solution would be to declare int age outside of main, in the class. This would allow all of your functions to access it.

Comment: @user1308743 your second solution would not work as the program was written. The `age` parameter to `InputMembershipStatus` would take precedence over the `age` class member, so the `age` declared outside of `InputMembershipStatus` would not have been affected.

Answer (score 0):

In `Main` add:

```
int age = 22; //initialize it
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `age` is used for the first time in the call to `InputMembershipStatus(age);` so the compiler suppose that it exists there declared as a local variable or at the global class level, but there is no declaration of that variable local or global and thus you get the error message.

The first thing to do to fix your program is to change the `InputMembershipStatus` removing the passed in `age` (not really needed) and return the value asked to the user. A conventional value of -1 is used as a way to signal that the user hasn't entered a correct age value.

```
    public static int InputMembershipStatus()
    {
        int age = -1;
        Console.WriteLine("Are you a Club Member? <Y or N>: ");
        string aValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (aValue == "Y" || aValue == "y" || aValue == "Yes" || aValue == "yes")
        {
            age = InputAge();
        }
        else if (aValue == "N" || aValue == "n" || aValue == "No" || aValue == "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, discounts apply to Club Members only.");
            TerminateProgram();
        }
        return age;
    }
```

then you could fix your `main` function to get this value back and pass it to `DetermineDiscount`

```
// Ask the age to the user and store it in a local variable here
int age = InputMembershipStatus();

// If we have received a valid value for age, 
// pass that local value to the DetermineDiscount function
if(age != -1)
    DetermineDiscount(age);

TerminateProgram();
```

Finally, another important fix is required in the `InputAge` method. (not related to your main problem, but important nevertheless)

```
   public static int InputAge()
   {
        int age;
        Console.Write("Please enter the customer's age: ");
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
            return age;
        else
            return -1;

   }
```

Here you need to check the user input. Using `Convert.ToInt32` on a non numeric input will crash the program with an exception (try to press enter without any input, a blank string will have the same effect). Instead a [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) will try to convert the input in a valid integer value and if it is successful will return with a true value and the converted number in the passed argument. Again return a conventional value of -1 to indicate an invalid age input and terminate the program